# Self-organizing maps

Tags: differential-geometry, geometry

I'm currently interested in this subject but all I can see is about neural networks and I'm more interested on the Theoretical point of view: "how can a system (Lagrangian/Hamiltonian) alter it's geometry by external perturbations?" (If I got that right... of course)

Some directions here?

Comment: Maybe it's just that I'm unfamiliar with the field, but it's not clear to me what you're actually asking here. Can you try to make this more specific?

Comment: Let see... You have a lattice that can change its geometry depending on the perturbations you throw "in". Hope it helps

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. I guess the root of the problem is that you end your question with "Some directions here?" which is a _really_ vague way to ask a question. That's what I'm asking if you can clarify.

Comment: Lagrangian/Hamiltonian dynamics is a bad fit for these types of questions. You are probably best off making a direct discrete computational model, and ignoring the real numbers, which add unnecessary complications.

Comment: I'm sorry @DavidZaslavsky but if I ask for directions (something to read) is just because I don't see where I can get this information.

Comment: @RonMaimon why is a bad fit for these type of systems? When I first read about this I thought there should be some "kind of" atractor to describe them.

Comment: @fenix: when you say "self organizing", I think of "self-organized criticality" and "self organizing cellular automata", both of which are best explained in discrete models (although the critical models have scaling limits). The idea of a self-organizing Hamiltonian system is overkill--- you have too much structure in the Hamiltonian system already which will be irrelevant for the self organization. Also, Hamiltonian systems are always quasi-periodic, so if you want self-organization, you have to arrange part of the system to be an energy sink.